# Laravel, log in user for one request

Tags: laravel

I am building a REST API with Laravel, and I have a filter that checks for a TOKEN:

```
Route::filter('api.auth', function() {

    $token = Request::header('X-CSRF-Token') ? Request::header('X-CSRF-Token') : '';

    if (empty($token)) {
        return Response::json(
            ['message' => 'A valid API key is required!'],
            401
        );
    };

    $user = User::where('token', '=', $token);

    if ($user->count()) {
        $user = $user->first();
        Auth::login($user);
    } else {
        return Response::json(
            ['message' => 'Your token has expired!'],
            401
        );
    };
});
```

If everything is ok, the filter will log in the user with `uth::login($user);`

How can I log him for only 1 request?

Since this filter is going to be checked on every request, I think it would be better to log the user out each time.

I have seen this in Laravel's docs, not sure how to apply it:

```
if (Auth::once($credentials))
{
    //
}
```

Could I have a callback in my response? where I could log the user out?

/*
    Get all products.
*/
public function getProducts() {

```
$products = Auth::user()->products;

return Response::json($products, 200);
```

}

Any ideas?

Comment: Use a tested and proven [package](https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel) for laravel API, oauth2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I correctly understand the question then I would say that, just replace following

```
Auth::login($user);
```

with this (To log the user in only for current request):

```
Auth::once(['email' => $user->email, 'password' => $user->password]);
```

If you log in a user only for once then you don't have to manually logo out the user, the user will be asked again for to log in on next request.

Answer (score 12):

If you haven't user's password use this:

```
if(Auth::onceUsingId($userId)) {
    // do something here
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to use the `web` guard.